Pairwse Buffer using table of values
I'm trying to use a list of items that reference a distance to then use in a buffer. I'm having a hard time getting the table to work. I'm trying to create a drop down so they'd select Item1 and it would input the distance.
import os
import sys
import arcpy
##Paramaters
Workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Workspace
Selection = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Selection
Item = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # Item
FP1 = os.path.abspath(Workspace)
##LIst of Item Distances
Item1 = "8000 meters"
Item2 = "1500 meters"
Item3 = "5000 meters"
##Pairwise Buffer
arcpy.analysis.PairwiseBuffer(Selection, fr"{FP1}\Buffer%n%", Item, "ALL", None, "GEODESIC", "0 DecimalDegrees")

But I keep getting this error.
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.ERROR 000728: Field Autel_Alpha does not exist within table
Failed to execute (PairwiseBuffer).

